# Related list on vf page to show the history of the custom object

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

i have VF page and i need to show the related lists also into the page.
i know i can use to show openactivities related list this way.

```
<apex:relatedList list="OpenActivities"/>
```

But the question that i have is that how do i show other related list. What the key words to show the history of the object

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean field tracking history? There is no keyword for that - you need use apex code to create the component. You might be able to make use of code here http://forums.sforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/History-related-List-using-Visualforce/m-p/156208#M18714

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
<apex:detail relatedList="true"/> for all detail
```

or

```
<apex:relatedList list="ActivityHistories" subject="{!account}"></apex:relatedList>
```

Comment: couldnt find any link or helpful information.. Thanks Adam and naomi for the link. that vertainly helped

Comment: That comment helped me. Thank you sushant and Prady for the comment.